# Is probability theory useful in electrical engineering

Tags: probability, learning

I have a two week holiday after finishing this semester and I was hoping to study something. Ideally, I would like to study something that I can benefit from in any upcoming courses I take. I'm thinking of either fourier series or probablity theory. Currently I'm leaning towards Fourier because it's very relevant to electrical engineering, however, Probablity theory seems intriguing to me (also opens up interesting areas such machine learning).

So how relevant is probablity theory to undergraduate electrical engineering ?!

Comment: Maybe ask an electrical engineer?

Comment: Consider [electronics.se], though I'm not certain it's on topic there.

Comment: I asked the engineers too :). I did not know where the question fits best, so I thought it's appropriate to ask both the engineers and the mathematicians. The question is certainly in the grey :)

Comment: @Alizter Emmanuel Candes a mathematician pioneered many aspects of probability theory in electrical engineering. This question I think fits here as well as anywhere.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii please see my comment to Alizter.

Comment: This is a rigorous probability book written by an electrical engineer! http://www.amazon.com/The-Theory-Probability-Explorations-Applications/dp/1107024471. Also, Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course by Achim Klenke has a whole chapter devoted to markovian electric network analysis. Anything involving noisy signals or variable demand is ideally suited for prob. theory. It's also highly relevant in IT design (routers, servers) for optimizing for stochastic badwith usage.

Comment: Of all the engineering disciplines, I've seen electrical engineers rely most heavily on advanced prob. theory (right after my own specialty...Operations Research ;-)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability is relevant to electrical engineering.  Just look at sparse sampling and Kalman filtering.  Sparse sampling (compressed sensing) has applications in MRI, photography, cameras, networks, etc.

Look up Emmanuel Candes at Stanford http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/.  I believe he invented sparse sampling.

Image coding for jpeg by decorrelation is another example. Kalman filtering is used in Feedback and Optimal Control. I forgot a big one signal processing as well.

[Kalman Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)

[Compressed Sensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing)

[JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)

[Signal Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing)